# Implementing Interstitial ads with AdMobs with the JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, admob, interstitial

Is it possible to start an interstitial ad by calling a Java method from C++?
What I am trying to do is at a certain point in my game call the java method and from there it starts the interstitial ad. The problem is it's straight up crashing the app.

I've implemented several other java methods to do things like submit achievements, leaderboard scores, etc. But calling the interstitial ad is crashing the app.

Here is what I do:

At the top of activity:

```
InterstitialAd interstitial;
```

In the onCreate method

```
// Create the interstitial.
interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
interstitial.setAdUnitId(MY_AD_UNIT_ID);

// Create ad request.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

// Begin loading your interstitial.
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Implemented java method called from C++ code:

```
public void googleDisplayAd()
{       
    if (interstitial.isLoaded())
    {
        Log.v("googleplay", "interstitial loaded");
        interstitial.show();
    }
}
```

It gets as far as the interstitial.isLoaded() and crashes there.

Here is an upload of the text with crash information: http://pastebin.com/XRT5uBxq

```
02-09 23:16:40.828: I/DEBUG(8990): [02-09 23:16:40.844]
02-09 23:16:40.828: I/DEBUG(8990): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-09 23:16:40.828: I/DEBUG(8990): Build fingerprint: 'lge/fx3s_spr_us/fx3:4.1.2/JZO54K/LS720ZV6.1383787089:user/release-keys'
02-09 23:16:40.828: I/DEBUG(8990): pid: 21335, tid: 21345, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> com.ronkrepps.chaindrop <<<
02-09 23:16:40.828: I/DEBUG(8990): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000050
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     r0 60ad71c8  r1 20600001  r2 60ad71c8  r3 00000051
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     r4 5747f7f0  r5 5d4cbaf0  r6 00000000  r7 51878f30
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     r8 5db19c80  r9 51878f28  sl 5d4cbb00  fp 5db19c94
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     ip 4032aaa1  sp 5db19c78  lr 4032aab9  pc 00000050  cpsr a0000030
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d0  00000001000f0003  d1  0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000057477fc0
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d4  ffffffff00000001  d5  0000000012000008
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d6  01080ff000020000  d7  000000304e47d120
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.249: I/DEBUG(8990):     d16 0000000057477b70  d17 0000000100030101
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d18 41483f7800000000  d19 c0000000400a60b0
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d20 401a6a9c00000020  d21 00000bbbbe8958b8
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d22 41cf15d000000404  d23 0000003533333132
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d24 3fd99a27ad32ddf5  d25 3fe555b0aaeac752
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d28 0000000000000005  d29 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     scr 20000010
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990): backtrace:
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #00  pc 00000050  <unknown>
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #01  pc 00065ab7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #02  pc 0001fcf0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #03  pc 0004ea51  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+360)
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #04  pc 000291a0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #05  pc 0002d968  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+180)
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #06  pc 00060059  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+272)
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #07  pc 00060083  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
02-09 23:16:41.259: I/DEBUG(8990):     #08  pc 000554ab  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):     #09  pc 00012f30  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):     #10  pc 00012688  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990): stack:
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c38  57233fe0  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c3c  408f5c07  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c40  40951578  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c44  5d4cbaf0  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c48  5d4cbaf0  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c4c  00000000  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c50  51878f70  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c54  4016b8f1  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+56)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c58  40951578  /system/lib/libdvm.so
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c5c  401a6a9c  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c60  5d4cbaf0  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c64  00000000  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c68  41cfa710  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c6c  5d4cbaf0  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c70  df0027ad  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c74  00000000  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):     #00  5db19c78  51878f5c  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          ........  ........
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):     #01  5db19c78  51878f5c  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c7c  408c2cf4  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):     #02  5db19c80  51878f24  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c84  00000001  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c88  41cfa710  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c8c  00000000  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c90  00000000  
02-09 23:16:41.269: I/DEBUG(8990):          5db19c94  408f1a55  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+364)
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r0:
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71a8 ff90bcff ffffffff ffffffff 199fffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71b8 fffffdc4 ffffffff 20cbfeff 00000051  ........... Q...
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71c8 5d43c980 4019f5a4 62050670 00000000  ..C]...@p..b....
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71d8 00000000 70612f61 ffffffff ffffffff  ....a/ap........
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71e8 00010c50 00000000 00024ae4 00000000  P........J......
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r1:
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     205fffe0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     205ffff0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     20600000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     20600010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     20600020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r2:
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71a8 ff90bcff ffffffff ffffffff 199fffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71b8 fffffdc4 ffffffff 20cbfeff 00000051  ........... Q...
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71c8 5d43c980 4019f5a4 62050670 00000000  ..C]...@p..b....
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71d8 00000000 70612f61 ffffffff ffffffff  ....a/ap........
02-09 23:16:41.279: I/DEBUG(8990):     60ad71e8 00010c50 00000000 00024ae4 00000000  P........J......
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r4:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5747f7d0 00001682 590a63e1 4032a5e5 00000000  .....c.Y..2@....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5747f7e0 408f18e9 00000100 00000000 00000000  ...@............
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5747f7f0 41488440 00000112 00020000 00020000  @.HA............
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5747f800 590e8ce9 4005d880 000016b4 590a6fb9  ...Y...@.....o.Y
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5747f810 4032aaa1 00000000 408f18e9 00000100  ..2@.......@....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r5:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbad0 408a1368 5d4cbfb8 00000000 00000013  h..@..L]........
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbae0 408a1368 5d4cb298 00000000 00000453  h..@..L]....S...
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbaf0 58c41722 51878f24 5747f5c0 5947f000  "..X$..Q..GW..GY
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbb00 41483e88 00011f0e 5db19da8 00000000  .>HA.......]....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbb10 5db19ddc 00000007 00000000 408c2e80  ...]...........@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r7:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f10 51878f40 58c41a00 5747f7f0 00000000  @..Q...X..GW....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f20 00000000 20600001 60ad71c8 51878f5c  ......` .q.`\..Q
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f30 58c41732 5747f5c0 58c41a00 00000000  2..X..GW...X....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f40 41cfa710 60ad71c8 51878f80 58c41778  ...A.q.`...Qx..X
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f50 575790b8 58c41732 00000000 41cfa710  ..WW2..X.......A
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r8:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c60 5d4cbaf0 00000000 41cfa710 5d4cbaf0  ..L].......A..L]
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c70 df0027ad 00000000 51878f5c 408c2cf4  .'......\..Q.,.@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c80 51878f24 00000001 41cfa710 00000000  $..Q.......A....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c90 00000000 408f1a55 51878f24 590a6fb9  ....U..@$..Q.o.Y
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19ca0 4032aaa1 5d4cbb00 00000000 00000000  ..2@..L]........
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near r9:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f08 00000000 00000000 51878f40 58c41a00  ........@..Q...X
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f18 5747f7f0 00000000 00000000 20600001  ..GW..........`
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f28 60ad71c8 51878f5c 58c41732 5747f5c0  .q.`\..Q2..X..GW
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f38 58c41a00 00000000 41cfa710 60ad71c8  ...X.......A.q.`
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     51878f48 51878f80 58c41778 575790b8 58c41732  ...Qx..X..WW2..X
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near sl:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbae0 408a1368 5d4cb298 00000000 00000453  h..@..L]....S...
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbaf0 58c41722 51878f24 5747f5c0 5947f000  "..X$..Q..GW..GY
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbb00 41483e88 00011f0e 5db19da8 00000000  .>HA.......]....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbb10 5db19ddc 00000007 00000000 408c2e80  ...]...........@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5d4cbb20 00000000 00000000 56a0d270 51875300  ........p..V.S.Q
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near fp:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c74 00000000 51878f5c 408c2cf4 51878f24  ....\..Q.,.@$..Q
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c84 00000001 41cfa710 00000000 00000000  .......A........
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c94 408f1a55 51878f24 590a6fb9 4032aaa1  U..@$..Q.o.Y..2@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19ca4 5d4cbb00 00000000 00000000 40951a6c  ..L]........l..@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19cb4 401a6a9c 00020102 5d4cbaf0 ffffbfff  .j.@......L]....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near ip:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aa80 0107f10d 46106883 47982201 bf082801  .....h.F.".G.(..
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aa90 0007f89d f04fd001 bd0e30ff 0003f4a4  ......O..0......
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aaa0 b92ab508 44794905 4008e8bd ba56f02e  ..*..IyD...@..V.
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aab0 68436810 47984610 bf00bd08 0003f474  .hCh.F.G....t...
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aac0 4ff0e92d 4604b0a5 461e4693 9d2f9f2e  -..O...F.F.F../.
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): memory near sp:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c58 40951578 401a6a9c 5d4cbaf0 00000000  x..@.j.@..L]....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c68 41cfa710 5d4cbaf0 df0027ad 00000000  ...A..L].'......
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c78 51878f5c 408c2cf4 51878f24 00000001  \..Q.,.@$..Q....
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c88 41cfa710 00000000 00000000 408f1a55  ...A........U..@
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     5db19c98 51878f24 590a6fb9 4032aaa1 5d4cbb00  $..Q.o.Y..2@..L]
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): code around pc:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  ................
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990): code around lr:
02-09 23:16:41.289: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aa98 bd0e30ff 0003f4a4 b92ab508 44794905  .0........*..IyD
02-09 23:16:41.299: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aaa8 4008e8bd ba56f02e 68436810 47984610  ...@..V..hCh.F.G
02-09 23:16:41.299: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aab8 bf00bd08 0003f474 4ff0e92d 4604b0a5  ....t...-..O...F
02-09 23:16:41.299: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aac8 461e4693 9d2f9f2e 49f2b92a f7d54479  .F.F../.*..IyD..
02-09 23:16:41.299: I/DEBUG(8990):     4032aad8 4658ecd6 9930e1d4 49efb929 f7d54479  ..XF..0.)..IyD..
```

Comment: What does it crash with? Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Yes I do. It just completely shuts down the app, no error messages besides the stack trace. I will edit the post to add a pastebin of the crash data. http://pastebin.com/XRT5uBxq

Comment: What don't you paste the stacktrace here? Pastebin is blocked by many proxies (such as the one I am behind).

Comment: I pasted it into the original post, sorry!

Comment: How do you know it gets that far? Is googleDisplayAd() being called? Has onCreate been called (ie have you previously created InterstitialAd?). Add some log, it will really help you find out these things.

Comment: I did add some log you can see in the googleDisplayAd I have Log.v("googleplay", "interstitial loaded"); If I comment out the code having to do with the interstitial in this method it runs and returns fine. I placed a log message inside to ensure it was getting to this method and running it.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to publish the code you are actually using (with its log messages) and likewise the if you want people to be able to readily help you.

I suspect that the interstitial attribute is null at the time that googleDisplayAd() is called. But without seeing the code and log it is very hard to know. Add the following log to googleDisplayAd().

```
Log.d(TAG, "interstialAd=" + interstitial);
```

Does it have a non-null value?